# Setting defaults in subclass backbone

Tags: javascript, inheritance, backbone.js, underscore.js

I have a superclass

```
var mySuperClass = Backbone.Model.extend({
     defaults: { ... }
});

var mySubClass = mySuperClass.extend({
     defaults: _.extend(mySuperClass.prototype.defaults, { 
         childDefault1: ..
     }
})
```

It works perfectly, It overwrite every value I need to overwrite but, if I create a `new mySubClass` with `options` like: `new mySubClass({someDefault: value})` the `someDefault` `property` won't set. 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

Use _.defaults

```
var SuperBook = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        author: "test",
        pages: 525
    }
});

var MiniBook = SuperBook.extend({
    defaults: {
        description: "mini book"            
    }
});

_.defaults(MiniBook.prototype.defaults, SuperBook.prototype.defaults); 


var myModel = new MiniBook({ author: 'default author', description : 'default description' })
```

Thanks